# You flip 4 coins, you get one dollar each time a head appears, given you know that at least two heads will appear what is the Expected pay off?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I have tried this problem with two approaches, and get two different answers, but don't understand why either approach is wrong.

Approach 1:

We know there will always be two heads, and the expected winnings for a remaining two-flip game is 1, so

E(X) = 2 + 1 = 3.

Approach 2:

Where '2H' denotes at least 2 heads, which has probability 11/16 (1-three and four tails cases)

$E\left( X|2H\right)  = \sum ^{4}_{x=2}p\left( x|2H\right) x = \sum ^{4}_{x=2}x\dfrac {P \left( x\cap 2H\right) }{P \left( 2H\right)  }$

= $ \dfrac {16}{11} \sum ^{4}_{x=2}xp\left( x\right) = \dfrac {28}{11}$

Can anyone see the error and why?

Comment: Checking by simulation in R: Code `x = rbinom(10^6, 4, 1/2);  mean(x[x>=2])` performs the experiment a million times, which should give answer correct to two places. Result from one run: `2.545608`, compared with $28/11 = 2.545455.$

Comment: @BruceET, cool!, nice to know it is the right answer, it would be fun to learn R or python to try out these things. Did you learn by yourself?

Comment: Learned R by myself, but it was part of my job. Lots of good online help. The best approach is gradually learn just the parts you need at each moment. Trying to learn all of R would be futile; new libraries and procedures are added faster than anyone could keep current with. R has excellent programmers who work as a contribution to their profession, rigorous standards of review, open source code so anyone can check it. Once a student of mine was absolutely sure he'd found a small error, reported it, and it was fixed quickly. Python is also excellent, useful software. Have not learned it yet.

Comment: ah I see, what is your job if you don't mind me asking, a lecturer?—I'm a graduate interviewing for different areas, and want to use maths. Thanks for the advice, I appreciate it.

Comment: Most recently, mostly professor. Also book author, consultant, gov't bureaucrat from time to time.

Comment: Nice, a maths professor? wow, a few vocations.. Well thank you for helping out on here. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment continued:* You made a good start (+1), @jorki has pointed out the right approach (+1), and simulated results approximate that approach. Summarizing the computation, we
have:

The original (unconditional) distribution is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(4, 1/2),$
which has probabilities $p = (1, 4, 6, 4, 1)/16$ for outcomes $x = (0,1,2,3,4)$ Heads.

Conditionally on $X \ge 2$ the probabilities are $p^\prime = (6, 4, 1)/11$ for outcomes $x^\prime = (2,3,4).$

Thus, the conditional mean is $[2(6) + 3(4) + 4(1)]/11 = 28/11.$

Comment: Seems pretty simple when written like that!, so I can't trust whoever wrote this guide, I thought the first method seemed a bit fishy

Comment: Most guides, back-of-book answers, student manuals, etc. have a few errors. Many of them confirmed on this site. Your guide may still be mostly useful.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is the right one. In the first approach, you're calculating the expectation under the condition that two *particular* results are heads and you know nothing about the other two, but that's not the information that you actually have. Try it with $1$ out of $2$ instead of $2$ out $4$; I think that will make it clearer what's going wrong.

Comment: I got this question at https://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/interview-guides/quantitative-trading.pdf  at question 26. So this guide just seems to have wrong answers...

Comment: Ok, thank you, it seems a subtle point, I calculated the answer wrong in method 2, so I hope 28/11 is the correct answeer. with 1 out of 2 I get 4/3 as opposed to 3/2, I think I understand, I can see that approach 2 is definitely right. the first result is not incoporating that the other two are related to the two results being heads.

Comment: @Tinatim: Interesting that an interview guide for quantitative trading contains such a serious error.